# Disable Managed Metadata field

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, form

How could I disable a managed metadata field?. I'm pulling the information of that field from another List and I don't want the user to modify its value

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? You mean you want user to only read data from the list?

Comment: I don't want the user modify the values I'm setting in that field

Comment: Can't you disable the field by making it read only?

Comment: No i can't. Because it's a Managed Metadata field. So i don't know well what do i have to make read only, there certains divs and things that Sharepoint creates to managed this kind of field

Answer (score 0):

You can make the MMD field hidden, through PowerShell

Comment: Can you please add more details about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get-TermSet([string]$groupName, [string]$termSetName)
  {
  $termStore = Get-TermStoreDefault
  return $termStore.Groups[$groupName].TermSets[$termSetName]
  }


 $termSet = Get-TermSet $yourtermStorGroupName $yourtermSetName

 $taxoField = $yourweb.Fields.CreateNewField("TaxonomyFieldType",
  $displayName)

 taxoField.SspId = $termSet.TermStore.Id

 taxoField.TermSetId = $termSet.Id

 taxofield.AllowMultipleValues = $false

 taxofield.Group = $fieldGroup

 taxofield.StaticName = $staticName

 taxofield.ShowInEditForm = $false #here is the solution

 taxofield.ShowInNewForm = $false #here is the solution

 taxofield.Hidden = $true  #here is the solution

 taxofield.Required = $false

 $web.Fields.Add($taxofield);

 $web.Update();
```